# How do I remove the UV grid from this image?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm a beginner and just tried texture painting using this tutorial: [Youtube video](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbkNnagtrYAhUKzbwKHT6ZAS0QtwIIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVp3q56kTtLY&usg=AOvVaw2UW9T5QEAf1jm1ViRXyT_A)
At some point, I must have messed up. I applied the material and this is what I'm getting in render mode: [image]

This is the png file used in texture painting: [image]

How do I remove the grid thing? I want to have a metallic material and show these lines on top of it. So how can I remove the UV grid and show the lines on top of a new material?

Comment: You added that grid in the image somehow (maybe by baking atop of image with Blender's UV grid pattern) and then added paint on top of it. It's best to redo the image making it blank first and then painting on it. I don't think you can easily remove it, however if you really want to work with this image it should be possible to crop it with image editor

Comment: @MrZak can you post a link to a tutorial so help me with it? And can I do the latter option in Blender? If so, how?

Comment: To help with what? If redoing all you do is erase current image and create / rewrite it with new one. Then paint your details there again how you did it on this image. As to the latter no, I wouldn't do it in Blender, capabilties for precise selecting of image parts of popular image editors are better for this.

Comment: @MrZak a guy helped me on IRC #blender. http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=122573

Comment: Possibly post that image directly here as an answer to your question so others might find the solution.

Comment: That will work, note only that in case of fine / thin details in the image they might be lost / removed with ColorRamp and moving its color stops won't necessary turn them back without part of background to appear. Other than that nice solution

Comment: Well I might be missing the point, but for this actual image you could go into photoshop or GIMP and select by color and fill with white or whatever color you want. If you want to avoid that you can just make the brush reeally big and paint over the entire UV map, by setting the mode to Paint in the UV/Image editor window, then just drag your mouse across the whole thing. If you want it to be translucent later, do image editing.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
This solution was provided by a user on irc channel #Blender named JA12.
Also, please read Mr Zak's comments on the question.